# Importing xlsx and parsing to json

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, material-ui

I've set up a "drag and drop file" area on my webpage using material-ui-dropzone. Next, I installed SheetJS js-xlsx, which lets you parse xlsx data. My struggle is in getting the two to work together. I think I have the drag and drop file part working ok. But I am not sure how to deal with the next part. I have a function handleChange where I have tried various goes and I think it is just beyond my skill level.

Any ideas on what to put in there to parse the data to json? Or is SheetJS not the ideal tool for the job? I see it has nearly a million downloads on npm per week, while there is read-excel-file that only has 37K downloads per week, so I went wtih the SheetJS one.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { CSVReader } from "react-papaparse";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import { DropzoneArea } from "material-ui-dropzone";
import XLSX from "xlsx";

const testArray = [
  { ASIN: "ABC123", Rank: "£50", Sales: "£80" },
  { ASIN: "ZYX123&", Rank: "£70", Sales: "£20" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputText: "",
    outputText: "",
    parsedData: [],
    myRows: [],
    myColumns: [],
    files: null
  };
  columns;
  rows;

  handleChange = (files) => {
    this.setState({ files: files });
    // console.log(files);
    // console.log(this.state.files);
    // const workbook = XLSX.read(files);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> */}
        <Grid container justify="center">
          <Box mt={0} width={1100}>
            <Paper>
              <Box p={3} mt={2} mb={2}>
                <Grid container spacing={0}>
                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom={false}>
                      PPC Cruncher
                    </Typography>
                  </Grid>
                  {/* TODO: */}
                  <Grid item xs={6} align="right"></Grid>

                  <Grid item xs={12} align="right">
                    <DropzoneArea onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  </Grid>
                  {/* <Grid item xs={12} align="left">
                      <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                        <DataGrid
                          rows={this.state.myRows}
                          columns={this.state.myColumns}
                          pageSize={5}
                          checkboxSelection
                        />
                      </div>
                    </Grid> */}
                </Grid>
              </Box>
            </Paper>
          </Box>
        </Grid>

        {/* </ThemeProvider> */}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(App);
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this recently and for anyone encountering a similar problem, here is my solution:

```
// use onDrop instead of onChange
<DropzoneArea onDrop={(files) => this.handleChange(files)} />

handleChange = (files) => {
    // files is an array of file
    // if I just want the first file
    const file = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        let data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        let workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'array'});
        // find the name of your sheet in the workbook first
        let worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'];

        // convert to json format
        const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Most of the information here can be found on the [SheetJS documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx).